# ListView with pager bar scrollable

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using the `ListView` to display some array-like objects.

Now I want to add a pager bar at the bottom of the activity.

However found that the `pager bar` can not be scroll-able.  That's to say, the `pager bar` will be at the top of the activity.

While I want the `pager bar` scroll-able like the content of the `ListView`.

Is this possible?

I have through to extends the `ListView` and add the `pager bar`. However it seems that add a new view to the `ListView` require re-layout,re-measure and etc. Is there a live example?

Comment: i may not understand right. do you want the pagerbar as footer on the listview? so that it will be visible only when you scroll till the very bottom of the list?

Comment: @MarioLenci: Exactly right. :) . I know there is a method `addFooterView`. But I am not sure about two things: 1 does it can implement what I want . 2 I want implement this in xml config rather than code.

Comment: well... i think that nothing stop you to put a pagerBar as footer, only "problem" is that it will scroll out horizontally with the listView.